# Presenting & Writing Code to a Classroom of Students?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm not sure if this question belongs on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything close to answering it.

I'm teaching a class of students how to code in Objective-C. At the start it was relatively easy to go through the exercises (hello world, etc) However, as they learn more increasingly difficult concepts, it's becoming difficult for me too to teach.

Are there any tools on OSX that allow me to split the screen between Xcode and my own notes, or just make it easier for me to juggle teaching and writing code at the same time?

Comment: I don't think this belongs on SO either, but I like the question and do not think it deserves downvotes. As I'm voting to close, you might want to try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to project XCode for student to see and keep the notes on your screen. Following steps will allow you to do that (in Mountain Lion, instructions are different if you are using Mavericks but same concept):

- Open System Preference->Display->Arrangement
- Disable "Mirror Display". This window will now show you two displays, one for your mac and one for the projector.
- Drag the XCode window to the secondary display for student to see.

Answer (score 0):

BetterSnapTool -
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12

Cinch -
http://download.cnet.com/Cinch/3000-2094_4-75003534.html

Those are just too options of many "split screen" solutions you can find for OSX.

My teacher used a projector as a 2nd monitor and then just showed us Xcode. If he needed to show us something from a powerpoint or other documentation, he could simply drag it over to the 2nd monitor.